# Can I use forms authentication if machine is not part of a domain?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, workgroup

I have successfully configured forms authentication in an ASP.NET website and able to login using my domain's account. I am now deploying to out UAT server which is hosted on Amazon, UAT server is not part of a domain and it is on a workgroup, I have created a local user and trying to login but unable to login. I am have tried these user name combinations

machinename\username
.\username
username

Can I use forms authentication if machine is not part of a domain?

Comment: Yes that is what forms authentication is for. User will enter username and password, and your code will decide how to process the authentication, for example, validate them against AD, database or some other storage. You are confusing Windows Authentication with Forms Authentication.

Comment: would there be any code change if forms authentication is working fine with AD and now website moved to a machine which is not connected to any AD?